# Material-ui Tab clicking submit to go to the next page removes the tab. How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have these tabs to go to the next step. However, once clicking submits, this will go to the correct page, but this will also remove the tab.  How can I fix this?

I have recreated this in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-cloud-uxfe97?file=/src/App.js

```
function TabPanel(props) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box sx={{ p: 3 }}>
          <Typography component="span">{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

TabPanel.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  index: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.number.isRequired
};

function a11yProps(index) {
  return {
    id: `simple-tab-${index}`,
    "aria-controls": `simple-tabpanel-${index}`
  };
}

const Ordering = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: "divider" }}>
        <Tabs
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          aria-label="basic tabs example"
        >
          <Tab
            label="Step 1"
            {...a11yProps(0)}
            component={Link}
            to={`/step1`}
          />
          <Tab label="Step 2" {...a11yProps(1)} />
        </Tabs>
      </Box>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        <Step1 />
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        <Step2 />
      </TabPanel>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Ordering;
```

**Step1.js**

Navigating this to the `step2` component does go to the next page, but this will also remove the tab

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Step1 = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    navigate("/Step2");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Step1;
```

**Step2.js**

```
const Step2 = () => {
  return <div>Step2</div>;
};

export default Step2;
```

Comment: You're trying to change the tabs based on URL, right?

Comment: @Singh3y yes, you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you're not nesting your routes properly. So, For nested route you need to define a route inside another one. Refer this page https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route for more information.

Getting back to your question. You need to update your code in two place. First how the routes are defined.

```
<Route path="/page" element={<Page />}>
   <Route path="step1" element={<Step1 />} />
   <Route path="step2" element={<Step2 />} />
</Route>
```

Once, your routes are updated. You are linking your panels based on route. So, you need not define them again in your `Page` component. You can remove those component from there and just add code so that when tab is click you change your navigation bar url. Sadly `Tab` of mui doesn't support component property https://mui.com/api/tab/ . You have to do that manually. You can use `useNavigate` provided by react router dom. Your updated `Page` component would look like this

I have added comment // This is added. To see where I've made changes. Just in 2 places changes are required.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { Box, Tab, Typography, Tabs } from "@mui/material";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import Step1 from "./Step1";
import Step2 from "./Step2";

import { Link } from "react";
// hook is imported
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function TabPanel(props) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box sx={{ p: 3 }}>
          <Typography component="span">{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

TabPanel.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  index: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.number.isRequired
};

function a11yProps(index) {
  return {
    id: `simple-tab-${index}`,
    "aria-controls": `simple-tabpanel-${index}`
  };
}

const paths = ['/page/step1', '/page/step2']

const Ordering = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
//This is added
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
// This is added
    navigate(paths[newValue])
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: "divider" }}>
        <Tabs
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          aria-label="basic tabs example"
        >
          <Tab
            label="Step 1"
            {...a11yProps(0)}
            component={Link}
            to={`/step1`}
          />
          <Tab label="Step 2" {...a11yProps(1)} />
        </Tabs>
      </Box>
      {/* Removed tab panels from here */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Ordering;
```

Comment: @Signh3y Hello, once I click submit it shows the right URL but the tab does not change to step2

Comment: Hi, @PennieCorhon. I've the sandbox code here. https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-cloud-uxfe97?file=/src/App.js Can you also verify once if the route and url are correct. Is it /page/step1 and /page/step2

Comment: it was already fixed. Thank you so much for the help